# How to use substring function in sql to extract when length of value is unknown

Tags: sql

```
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on 
    substring('t1.column1',9,x)=t2.column2;
```

This is the SQL query. i want to do this join on value of column1 after first 9 characters. But the value of column1 is not always consistent in length. What should be the value of 'x' here?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_, all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve].

Comment: BTW, I'd try `substring(t1.column1,9)`.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be `like`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.column2 like '_________' || t1.column1;
-------------------------^ exactly 9 underscores
```

Note:  This idea should work in any database.  However, not all databases support the SQL Standard `||` string concatenation operator, so you might have to adjust the syntax.

Comment: t2.column2 like '_________' || t1.column1;   ** i am curious as to what this does?

Comment: @PushkarAnand . . . Look up how `like` works in the documentation for whatever database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. appreciated. I was actually wondering why you used ||

Comment: @PushkarAnand . . . It is the Standard SQL operator for string concatenation.  `concat()` is not Standard SQL.